# Type or namespace not found, when queuing build on VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have an MVC web app on which I have added few existing project(using add existing project on VS2015), I then installed all the packages such as entity framework 6.1.3). I am then using VSTS online to queue and release builds, I have created the build definition and added all variable as expected, however when I queue the builds, I get an error that reads "The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in the namespace" these errors(about 600) seems to be coming from the projects(the existing projects) that I have added to this new one.

What confuses me the most is the fact that the app seems to be working fine when running locally on my visual studio and all the packages were installed via nuget package manager.

Below is the screenshot of all the properties from the BuildSolution task
[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a "NuGet Installer" build task for restoring the packages on the build server before the "Build Solution" task?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question but there are other applications that are currently running on this server and have been deployed using the same mechanism

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit your build definition
2. Click Add Task> Select NuGet Restore task >Add (Before Visual Studio Build task)

[image]